# How many decimal digits does javascript accepts?

Tags: javascript

When i assign `var a=123456789.1234567898123` then its returning the value of a as `123456789.12345679`. I need the same value assigned to var a and not the value after round off

Can someone please help me out ?

Comment: JavaScript provides 64-bit IEEE 754 double-precision floating point. Because it's *binary* floating point, your question can't be answered exactly.

Comment: Is there any other way where we can customize this to get the expected output ?

Comment: look into https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/wiki and possibly use: https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript uses IEEE 754 floats.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)  While the limitations are based on binary numbers, you can take that to mean about 15-16 decimal digits of precision.  If you want more accuracy you're going to have to find yourself an arbitrary-precision numeric library (or just use strings if you're not interested in doing mathematical operations).